# Applying opacity to a image causes the absolute div also transparent

Tags: css, image, opacity, absolute

I have a image gallery of the following structure :

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="message">
        Welcome to gallery
    </div>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.message {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:20px;
    height:30px;
    width:140px;
    background:#333;
}
.gallery img {
    opacity:.85;
}
```

But this causes the div `message` also transparent ! How to prevent it and whats the reason for transparency ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6c6sB/)

Comment: I am not able to see transparent div. are you sure this is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the image an id so only the image's opacity is lower

```
#img{ opacity: 85%; }
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" id="img" />
```

Or you could use a class

```
.img{ opacity: 85%; }
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" id="img" />
```

So then your could would be something like this:

```
    <div class="gallery">
    <div class="message">
        Welcome to image gallery
    </div>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img"/>
</div>
#img{ opacity: 85%; }
.img{ opacity: 85%; }
.message {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:20px;
    height:30px;
    width:140px;
    background:#333;
}
```

Hope this helps you!
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xGh0stSn1p3r/HkkCE/)

Comment: This solution does not work for me on Safari7.. The image still has 100% opacity. When I change 85% to .85 the problem is still there..

Comment: You need to have the % sign after the value, if you don't have the % sign it won't know if its a percentage, or pixels or anything. You could possible try `.img{ opacity: .85%; }` if it will work in safari.

Comment: Try changing the css to `.img{ opacity: .85%; }` if you're using safari. I am using chrome so I don't really know why it's not working for safari, I will try to help you, but if I can't im sorry

Comment: 0.85% makes no sense.. opacity is a value between 0 and 1 in css. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: Try something like this `@-moz-document url-prefix() {
#img{ opacity: 0.1; }
}` for mozilla firefox

Comment: Nope.. still not working. Again, percentage values are not how you're supposed to specify opacity.. another short resource (http://www.css3files.com/color/#opacity)

Comment: Whenever I do it like 0.6 or something, it doesn't work so I use percentages

Answer (score 1):

It seems the image is on top of the message div. I just swapped them over like this:

> ```
> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
> <div class="message">
>     Welcome to image gallery
> </div>
> ```

And that fixed it for me.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c6sB/1/)

Another way is to give the message a z-index like this:

```
.message {
    position:absolute;
    left:150px;
    top:20px;
    height:30px;
    width:140px;
    background:#333;
    z-index: 2;
}

.gallery img {
    opacity:.85;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c6sB/2/)